# Maven copies folder content at the root of jar when generating

Tags: java, maven, jar, lwjgl

Good evening,
I'm creating a Java project and tries to build it with maven. The project needs LWJGL libraries, also, I added concerned dependencies in my pom.xml. However, I also need to include native LWJGL libraries to my project. For that, I created a folder called native in the same branch than the src folder and put native libraries in it. I use the following code to tell maven to include that folder in the jar :

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>${basedir}/native</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.*</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

and I use maven resources plugin to define where I want resources to be located in generated jar (under native folder).

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}\native</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I then generate the jar using `maven package` command. All works well in the generated jar but I need to package my LWJGL libraries in it too. Also, I tried to use maven-assembly-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin, and maven-shade-plugin . In the three cases, jar libraries are well packaged but my native ones are being all copied to the root of my Jar and I'm unable to explain why.
For obvious memory reasons, I don't want that to happen and I'd prefer not to remove them by hand.
Any ideas of how to solve that problem ?
Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you need want to include inside of your jars another jar, the solution is make a Fat jar.

Here an example.

```
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>

        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>

    </plugin>
```

But I'm not sure that you really want that... 
It is a posibility to include the jars inside the classpath or as a maven dependency?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.lwjgl/lwjgl -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
     <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, in fact, I already tried that, the jars where packaged but all native libraries from the native folder where copied at the root of the jar, any idea why ?